# what do these words have in common

Tags: language

libro,
livre,
libre,
leabhar,
kirja,
iphepha

What do these words have in common?

> Hint they are all from different languages which means that no that is not the answer because DIFFERENT.

Comment: May I offer a suggestion to you? This puzzle definitely has the roots of an interesting question, but is probably too direct (which is possibly why it has got some downvotes as well). The first 3 words are quite relatable to anyone who speaks popular European languages (including English). Then its just a matter of extrapolating it onto the last 3 words, and a quick bit of Google searching will easily give them the answer, as it did for me.

Comment: What would make this a nicer puzzle would be to follow through with finding words similar to the last three (which are not obvious), find a few more in similarly differentiated languages. Then, instead of framing a puzzle with just these words, it would be nice if you hid these words in some manner (in a maze of letters, a crossword, crossword clues, steganography, etc.), so people have to unravel the words first, and then find the common theme.

Comment: Do keep this in mind for your next puzzle, and I'm sure you'll see a nicer response to it, as well as people taking more time to work it out!

Comment: Another resource you can use is [the sandbox](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5276/the-riddle-sandbox). You can read that link for more info, but in brief, it's a place for you to present a riddle (or an idea), get feedback, improvement tips, etc. before you actually put it out here.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

They are all the word for

> **BOOK** in different languages
>
>  [LIBRO](https://translate.google.com/#es/en/libro)   - Italian
>  [LIVRE](https://translate.google.com/#fr/en/livre)   - French
>  [LIBRE](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/libre#Occitan)   - Occitan
>  [LEABHAR](https://translate.google.com/#ga/en/LEABHAR) - Irish
>  [KIRJA](https://translate.google.com/#fi/en/KIRJA)   - Finnish
>  [IPHEPHA](https://translate.google.com/#xh/en/iphepha) - Xhosa (also means paper)

Comment: Yes you are correct

Comment: @PythonDude29 Please remember to (at least *eventually*) mark the correct answer as such. (Click the ☑ under the voting buttons.) And [Welcome to Puzzling SE!](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/tour)

Comment: Livre is not Book in Portuguese, I think you meant French...

Comment: @GustavoGabriel - many thanks for pointing that out, I've now corrected it. Oddly, the link pointed to a French translation, but I typed Portuguese thanks to a brain fade!

Comment: @Chowzen Yes done

Comment: Thanks, @Bass , I have no excuse for that typo!